# How do I find the argument signature for and call an unexported method in a DLL if I have the symbol for it?

Tags: c++, dll, reverse-engineering, symbols

This is a dll built into Windows, [odbc32.dll](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms714562%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). The function is called LoadTraceDll()

The stackframe in Visual Studio 2008 is:

> odbc32.dll!LoadTraceDll()  + 0x42f bytes

I've used a PE Analyzer and I don't see that in the export list for odbc32.dll.

My questions are as follows:

- How do I determine the parameter types and return type (method signature)?
- How do I call it? Can I avoid calling its relative address?

Full stack trace is as follows:

```
ODBCTracer.dll!TraceVersion()  Line 2259    C++
odbc32.dll!LoadTraceDll()  + 0x42f bytes    
odbc32.dll!FInitTrace()  + 0xf3 bytes   
odbc32.dll!DllMain()  + 0x14692 bytes   
odbc32.dll!_CRT_INIT()  - 0x3e3 bytes   
ntdll.dll!LdrpRunInitializeRoutines()  + 0x1e8 bytes    
ntdll.dll!LdrpLoadDll()  - 0x336 bytes  
ntdll.dll!LdrLoadDll()  + 0x9e bytes    
KernelBase.dll!LoadLibraryExW()  + 0x13f bytes  
odbccp32.dll!LoadDM()  + 0x2a bytes 
odbccp32.dll!TracingPageProc()  + 0xc46 bytes   
user32.dll!UserCallDlgProcCheckWow()  - 0x180d bytes    
user32.dll!DefDlgProcWorker()  + 0xba bytes 
user32.dll!DefDlgProcW()  + 0x36 bytes  
user32.dll!UserCallWinProcCheckWow()  + 0x11d bytes 
user32.dll!InternalCreateDialog()  - 0xc7 bytes 
user32.dll!CreateDialogIndirectParamAorW()  + 0x5b bytes    
user32.dll!CreateDialogIndirectParamW()  + 0x18 bytes   
comctl32.dll!_CreatePageDialog()  + 0xb1 bytes  
comctl32.dll!_CreatePage()  + 0x161 bytes   
comctl32.dll!PageChange()  + 0xca bytes 
comctl32.dll!PropSheetDlgProc()  + 0x36e bytes  
user32.dll!UserCallDlgProcCheckWow()  + 0x11b bytes 
user32.dll!DefDlgProcWorker()  + 0xba bytes 
user32.dll!DefDlgProcW()  + 0x36 bytes  
user32.dll!UserCallWinProcCheckWow()  + 0x11d bytes 
user32.dll!SendMessageWorker()  + 0x158 bytes   
user32.dll!SendMessageW()  + 0x5d bytes 
comctl32.dll!CCSendNotify()  + 0xfbd bytes  
comctl32.dll!SendNotifyEx()  + 0x80 bytes   
comctl32.dll!ChangeSel()  + 0x2dc bytes 
comctl32.dll!Tab_OnLButtonDown()  + 0xfc bytes  
comctl32.dll!Tab_WndProc()  + 0x56d bytes   
user32.dll!UserCallWinProcCheckWow()  + 0x11d bytes 
user32.dll!DispatchMessageWorker()  + 0x12a bytes   
user32.dll!IsDialogMessageW()  + 0x102 bytes    
comctl32.dll!Prop_IsDialogMessage()  + 0x1f0 bytes  
comctl32.dll!_RealPropertySheet()  + 0x31b bytes    
comctl32.dll!_PropertySheet()  + 0x55 bytes 
odbccp32.dll!MainSheet()  + 0x18c bytes 
odbccp32.dll!SQLManageDataSources()  + 0x4b bytes   
odbcad32.exe!WinMain()  + 0x25b bytes   
odbcad32.exe!ODBC___GetSetupProc()  + 0x4ae bytes   
kernel32.dll!BaseThreadInitThunk()  + 0xd bytes 
ntdll.dll!RtlUserThreadStart()  + 0x21 bytes
```

Answer (score 1):

> How do I determine the parameter types and return type (method signature)?

You can't.

(Well, you can, to a certain level of confidence, but it calls for great reverse engineering skills. You have to disassemble the library, find how the function is defined and called, and from typical operation sequences and parameter/variable sizes, you can deduce what the type of the arguments and the return value **can be**)

> How do I call it? Can I avoid calling its relative address?

You can `dlopen()`... er... `LoadLibrary()` the DLL and then get its address using `GetProcAddres()`, store it in a function pointer, then call it:

```
HMODULE hndl = LoadLibrary("My.DLL");
void (*func)() = GetProcAddress(hndl, "MyFunction");
func();
```

Comment: That's kind of what I was afraid of.

Comment: @JustinDearing if you wanna have method signatures, switch to Objective-C and class-dump the library to be reverse engineered :P

Answer (score 1):

If you have the symbols (PDB file) of the image, you could retrieve the unexported symbols and their signatures if these are public (in the parlance of the PDB public vs. private). Using [DIA](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x93ctkx8%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) you can match the symbols with the associated image file. See [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/37456/How-To-Inspect-the-Content-of-a-Program-Database-P) for an example of how the mapping between PDB Symbols and image works.

Comment: That looks promising, lets see how deep this rabbit hole goes.